# What' wrong with INT %ebx?

Tags: assembly, x86

I this assembly code:

```
INT %ebx
```

GCC is giving me an error when trying to assemble it:

```
INT ERROR:mismatch operand type for 'int'.
```

Does this imply that the operand of instruction `INT` must be a constant like `INT $0X80`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, the operand of INT must be a constant. According to [the NASM x86 reference](http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html):

```
A.81 INT: Software Interrupt
INT imm8                      ; CD ib                [8086]

A.82 INT3, INT1, ICEBP, INT01: Breakpoints
INT1                          ; F1                   [P6] 
ICEBP                         ; F1                   [P6] 
INT01                         ; F1                   [P6]
INT3                          ; CC                   [8086]

A.83 INTO: Interrupt if Overflow
INTO                          ; CE                   [8086]
```

So `INT` takes an 8bit immediate value and non of the interrupt variants actually take an register.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you take a look at the [Intel Software Developers Manual, Volume 2A Instruction Set Reference, A-M](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), there are three variants for `INT`:

```
 Opcode   Instruction  Description
 CC       INT 3        Interrupt 3—trap to debugger.
 CD ib    INT imm8     Interrupt vector number specified by immediate byte.
 CE       INTO         Interrupt 4—if overflow flag is 1.
```

That's it - none that take register parameters.